# Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined when using Vue Carousel

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm using the latest version of Vue Carousel in my Nuxt JS application. It seems that I get errors on each of my blog posts whenever using the `universal` mode for Nuxt JS. If I take out Vue Carousel and do a standard `v-for` loop, the blogs show perfectly fine, there's something causing the error when using the carousel.

My code:

```
<carousel :paginationEnabled="false" :navigationEnabled="true" :perPageCustom="[[250, 1], [1024, 2]]">
              <slide v-for="blog in blogs.blogs" :key="blog.id" v-if="currentBlogDate >= blog.created && blog.created">
                <b-card class="text-center m-3 p-0 p-md-3">
                  <h4 class="display-4 font-weight-normal mb-3">{{ blog.title | striphtml | truncate(32, '...') }}</h4>
                  <b-card-text class="text-muted">{{ blog.body | striphtml | truncate(32, '...') }}</b-card-text>
                  <b-button :to="'/posts/view/' + blog.title" size="sm" variant="primary">Read More<i class="fas fa-angle-right pl-2"></i></b-button>
                </b-card>
              </slide>
            </carousel>
```

The error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your component is not optimized for server-side rendering.

Keep in mind that Nuxt.js universal has neither `window` nor `document` objects during server-side rendering.

Quick fix for you - is to wrap your SSR incompatible components with `<no-ssr></no-ssr>` component.

https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-no-ssr#the-lt-no-ssr-gt-component